# How to fill data in nested Lists based on Ids in C#?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

```
public class CarDTO
{
    public int CarId { get; set; }
    public string CarName { get; set; }
    public List<PolicySummaryDTO> PolicySummaries { get; set; } 
}

public class PolicySummaryDTO
{
    public long PolicyId { get; set; }
    public string PolicyName { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

I have `List<CarDTO> Cars` each car has already list of policies `List<PolicySummaryDTO> PolicySummaries`.
`PolicyId` is filled. But other properties like `PolicyName`, `Amount`, etc. are not.
The thing I need to do is get data from DB `_contex.PolicySummary` and I need to complete missing fields.

I know that I could do this in this way.

1. Get all PolicyIds
   `var policyIds = cars.SelectMany(t => t.PolicySummaries).Select(r => r.PolicyId);`
2. Get PolicyData based on Ids
   `var policyData = _context.PolicySummary.Where(t => policyIds.Contains(t.PolicyId));`
3. And then using *foreach* I can fill data.

   ```
   foreach (var car in cars)
   {
       foreach (var policy in car.PolicySummaries)
       {
           var policyDataToUse = policyData.Single(t => t.PolicyId == policy.PolicyId);
           policy.Amount = policyDataToUse.Amount;
           policy.PolicyName = policyDataToUse.PolicyName;
       }
   }
   ```

Everthing will works fine, but I wondering whether I can do it in more elegant way, maybe using somehow `LINQ JOIN` or something, or maybe my solution is totally correct?

---

EDIT - solution with dictionary

```
var policyIds = cars.SelectMany(t => t.PolicySummaries).Select(r => r.PolicyId);
var policyDict = _context.PolicySummary.Where(t => policyIds.Contains(t.PolicyId)).ToDictionary(t => t.PolicyId);

foreach (var car in cars)
{
    foreach (var policy in car.PolicySummaries)
    {
        var policyDataToUse = policyDict[policy.PolicyId];
        policy.Amount = policyDataToUse.Amount;
        policy.PolicyName = policyDataToUse.PolicyName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using EF? Or how do you map objects to entities?
If you are using any framework or ORM there should be a 'correct' way to get your properties. Please edit your question and give us more details on how your project is setup.

Comment: @nilsK Actually there is a tag 'entity-framework' in this question.

Comment: @Fabjan Yes, I added after his comment :)

Answer (score 1):

So first of all, why is the data not filled? You should be able to fill out the data in any related entities during the actual `Car` fetch from the DB using `.Include`.

```
var carEntity = _context.Cars.Where(predicate).Include(c => c.PolicySummaries).Single();
```

Secondly, your code suffers from a serious performance issue: `policyData` is an `IQueryable`. Every time you do `policyData.Single`, you send a new query to the database, look through all policies, filter the ones that have their `id` in `policyIds` and choose the appropriate one. This will be incredibly inefficient if there are many policies - every `foreach` iteration is a new query! What you should do is probably do something like:

```
var policyData = _context.PolicySummary.Where(t => policyIds.Contains(t.PolicyId)).ToList();
```

To fetch all related policies. This could also be inefficient if there are a lot of shared policies and you end up loading most of them at some point anyway, so if there's not like a billion policies in the DB this:

```
var policies = _context.PolicySummary.ToList();
```

could work even better. It's a time/memory tradeoff at this point, but please note that any of the above will be better than the current query-overload `foreach` you have.

Comment: It's because `PolicySummaryDTO` has one more List inside. And this `PolicyId` from `PolicySummaryDTO` is filled based on the first record from that list. It's complicated case, I know it. I don't wanted to complicate this question as well.

Comment: You still should be able to do that in a db fetch, but if you want it done separately then at least adhere to my second point. It should be alright efficiency-wise then.

Comment: Don't use `Single()` because it can throw exception if there is more than one item or no items at all. Use `SingleOrDefault()`. For more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619283/should-i-use-single-or-singleordefault-if-there-is-a-chance-that-the-element; 
http://www.technicaloverload.com/linq-single-vs-singleordefault-vs-first-vs-firstordefault/
P.S: I do not have any affiliation with this site.

Comment: Using `Single` or `SingleOrDefault` depends on what you want to achieve. If you're certain at that point in code that there _should_ be a record in the database with given `Id`, then use `Single`. I usually prefer my repositories to throw exceptions rather than return `null`s for non-exisiting entities, but it depends. Anyway, saying _don't use_ isn't a good advice. Both have their appropriate use cases.

Comment: It is a bad policy. Let's say you are working on an application that cannot stop working, you prefer that the application stops working? If it gives a default value, then you know that smth isn't right and you need to fix it.

Comment: Always crash early. It's way better to throw an exception and handle it - log an error, tell the user something went wrong and move on. If it shouldn't ever happen - it's an exception. If a default value is a sensible, usable value - return it. "Smth isn't right" always infers an exceptional situation that should be raised ASAP.

Comment: @Lewis86 - throw exception when error is an **exception** for your business logic. When only one record with particular id must exists in database, then `Single` would more comprehensible approach. Usually you catch all errors on the top layer of your application (UI or Web API), log them and display/return friendly error message for the user. Logged exception provide enough information about error cause. As a bonus rest of application don't need to deal "default" values, which will simplify code base.

Answer (score 0):

Because you already have existed DTO objects(not entities), you will not be able to effectively use of `Join` with EntityFramework.
You need to load missing data and then update existed car objects with it.

I think simpler way will be replace list of policies with objects retrieved from database.

```
var allPolicies = _context.PolicySummary
                          .Where(policy => policyIds.Contains(policy.PolicyId))
                          .Select(group => new PolicySummaryDTO
                          {
                              PolicyId = group.Key,
                              PolicyName = group.First().PolicyName,
                              Amount = group.First().Amount                  
                          })
                          .ToDictionary(policy => policy.PolicyId);

foreach (var car in cars)
{
    car.Policies = car.Policies.Select(p => p.PolicyId)
                               .Where(allPolicies.ContainsKey)
                               .Select(policyId => allPolicies[policyId])
                               .ToList();
}
```

Using `Dictionary` will keep updating code simpler and reduce amount of operations to execute, less loops.

Note: approach above assumes that all policies Id's exist in the database. If not, these will be removed from the correspondent `car.Policies` property. You can remove `Where(allPolicies.ContainsKey)` line and an exception will be thrown if some policies are missing.

Comment: There is no point in assigning a new collection to `car.Policies` when it's possible to flatten them and update a few fields in each element furthermore the `.ToList()` call will return a new collection which might or might not be a desirable behavior here

Comment: @Fabjan, as you said it _might or might not be a desirable behavior_ ;). As a benefit, you don't need to change updating code in case you will add/remove new properties to PolicySummaryDTO class.

Comment: Part with dictionary returns me `System.ArgumentException: 'An item with the same key has already been added. Key: 0'`

Comment: @DiPix, you can group items by `PolicyId` before creating a Dictionary, check updated answer.

Comment: Downvoter, please leave a comment, will be glad to fix or delete my answer.

Comment: This change makes ClientEvaluationWarning

Comment: @DiPix, materialize query before grouping. Put `.ToList()` after `.Where` clause.

Comment: It's not helping. After that again is: `'An item with the same key has already been added. Key: 0'`

Comment: @DiPix, add `.ToList()`, but do not remove `GroupBy`. `GroupBy` will remove duplicate `PolicyId` before creating a dictionary.

Comment: @Fabio anyway your soulution override existing object. Actually I'd like to update because this `PolicySummaryDTO` might have other values already assigned.

Comment: @Fabio check my Edit, I slightly refactored it. I used dictionary. Would be efficient now? It's shorter than your solution, and I think less complicated, you can suggest how I can improve it better if you know how, thanks :)

Comment: Your solution is exactly what @Fabjan suggested in his answer.