# PowerShell catch exception in Param() block

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

```
Param(
    [ValidateRange(21,90)]
    [int[]]$Age
)
```

How to catch exception when `$age` is out of range?

Comment: Exceptions from parameter validation must be caught by the caller. It can't be caught in the `Param()` block. That would defeat the purpose of parameter validation.

Comment: so what is the main purpose of [ValidateRange] if i cant catch an exception?

Comment: Save exceptions for [exceptional situations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/180937/503046). It's generally expected that users will provide inappropriate parameter values.`[citation needed`]

Comment: The purpose is to ensure that the script or function is only run if the parameter received valid values and is not run otherwise. If you want parameters to accept anything and deal with whatever value you're getting yourself: don't use parameter validation. Do your own type checking in the function/script body (for instance in a `Begin {}` block).

Comment: Besides, I didn't say you can't catch the exception. I said you can't catch it in the `Param()` block.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - how does one catch the error from the calling context? i added `[CmdletBinding()]` & have tired `-ErrorAction`, `-ErrorVariable`, and redirecting the error stream ... they all fail to stop the display of that error. it DOES end up in the `$Error` automatic variable ... but i see no way to stop the _display_ of the red error text.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey That depends on what the calling context actually is. Running a PowerShell script from a non-PowerShell environment requires different handling than calling a function from within a PowerShell script.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers  - i took the OPs code, made a function of it, added `[ComdletBinding()]` to it and one line of output using `$Age`. i cannot find any way to prevent a red error text block from showing up in the ISE or in the powershell console when i use this call >>> `Test-RangeValidation -Age 1` <<< it seems like there SHOULD be a way to capture that so it does not interrupt the output AND so it allows one to gracefully handle it. **_i am lost for ideas ... the OPs question seems quite on-point to me._**

Comment: This block should accept parameters while script starts up , i'm not using this block for functions

Comment: Then the error handling depends on how you invoke the script. From within PowerShell: use `try { & 'C:\path\to\your.ps1' -Age 4 } catch {...}` when calling the script. From outside PowerShell: redirect the error output stream and evaluate the exit code.

Answer (score 1):

As has been pointed out in the comments, the validation error needs to be caught in the calling context

```bsh
try{
  .\Set-Age.ps1
}
catch [System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingException] {
  Write-Host "Error thrown while attempting to bind an argument to parameter $($_.Exception.ParameterName), with message: $($_.Exeption.Message)"
}
catch {
  # something other than the parameter binder threw an exception
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This example function may be helpful. It shows the Parameter validation script throwing an exception that is a bit more complicated than just a plain string. I was trying to catch the validation 'exception' within the validation script itself, but, in fact, that is not necessary. Just throw an arbitrarily complicated exception message, or possibly a user-defined exception object of a particular type. The 'complicated' message or the custom exception object gets through to the wrapper catch block for 'catch-all' exceptions

```
function Get-FullPath {
    [OutputType([System.String])]
    [CmdletBinding()]   
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
        [ValidateScript({            
              
                if ( -Not ($_ | Test-Path) ) {
                    $excMsg = $("`nError: File or folder does not exist {0}" -f ("`nValue: $_" ) )
                    throw $excMsg
                }                                       
            })]
        [System.IO.FileInfo]$Path,             
        [System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter]
        $Directory # switch  will evaluate to $false if not passed
    )
    try {       
        Write-Debug  ('Path {0}: ' -f $Path)
        Write-Debug  ('Directory Only {0}: ' -f $Directory)
 
        $result = ( ( $Directory ) ?  $Path.Directory : $Path )
        $result | Write-Output | Write-Debug 
    
        return
    }
    catch [System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingException] {
        Write-Host "Error thrown while attempting to bind an argument to parameter $($_.Exception.ParameterName), with message: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    }
    
    catch {
        $_.Exception.Message | Write-Debug
        <#Do this if a terminating exception happens#>
    }
```

}

and generates this:

```
PS> Get-FullPath -Path 'some-bad-filenme.ps1' -Debug 
Get-FullPath: Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Path'. 
Error: File or folder does not exist 
Value: some-bad-filenme.ps1
```